# Using Watir to click on Radio Buttons with variable values

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm getting in trouble while trying to click on Radio Button.

The HTML code is:

```
function radioButtonFormatter(el, oRecord, oColumn, oData) {
var checkFalse='checkFalse';
var check='check'     ;


el.innerHTML="<input type='radio' name='table-radiobutton' value='" + oData + "' onclick='disableButtons(this.checked, this.type)' />";        
}
```

I'd like to use something like:

```
browser.radio(:value => "oData").click
```

But it's not working...I also tried to use a piece of text as reference, but it didn't work as well.

Do you guys have any suggestion on how to perform it? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the html of the radio buttons that get created?

Answer (score 3):

> But it's not working

Yes.  When a page defines a js function like this:

```
function radioButtonFormatter(el, oRecord, oColumn, oData) {
var checkFalse='checkFalse';
var check='check'     ;


el.innerHTML="<input type='radio' name='table-radiobutton' value='" + oData + "' onclick='disableButtons(this.checked, this.type)' />";        
}
```

...it does not cause the function to execute.  If you executed this ruby program:

```
def greet
  puts 'hello'
end
```

...would you wonder why there was no output?  Similarly, the radio button doesn't exist until you execute the js function.

Next, this:

```
browser.radio(:value => "oData").click
```

looks for a radio button with the attribute:

```
<radio value="oData" ...>
```

What you want is:

```
browser.radio(:value => oData).click
```

However, that means you have to create a variable called oData, and assign it a value:

```
oData = "something here"
browser.radio(:value => oData).click
```

Writing the variable name oData in a ruby program does not magically make it have the same value as a variable called oData in a javascript program.

Here are some things you *can* do:

3.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>index.html</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function disableButtons(x, y) {
  document.getElementById("disable-info").innerHTML = x + " " + y;
}

function radioButtonFormatter(el, oData) {
  var checkFalse='checkFalse';
  var check='check'     ;


  el.innerHTML="<input type='radio' name='table-radiobutton' value='" + oData + "' onclick='disableButtons(this.checked, this.type)' />";        
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div>Hello world</div> 
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="disable-info"</div>
</body>
</html>
```

.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

b.goto "http://localhost:8080/3.htm"

b.execute_script(
  "radioButtonFormatter(
    document.getElementById('div1'), 42
  )"
)

b.radio(:value => "42").click
```

Or, if the radioButtonFormatter() function is triggered by some event, you can fire that event with watir-webdriver:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>index.html</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function disableButtons(x, y) {
  document.getElementById("disable-info").innerHTML = x + " " + y;
}

function radioButtonFormatter(el, oData) {
  var checkFalse='checkFalse';
  var check='check'     ;


  el.innerHTML="<input type='radio' name='table-radiobutton' value='" + oData + "' onclick='disableButtons(this.checked, this.type)' />";        
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('greeting').onclick = function() {
    radioButtonFormatter(document.getElementById('div1'), 42);
  }
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="greeting">Hello world</div> 
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="disable-info"</div>

</body>
</html>
```

.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

b.goto "http://localhost:8080/3.htm"

b.div(id: "greeting").when_present.click  #This causes radioButtonFormatter() to execute
b.radio(value: "42").when_present.click
```

But that does not let you control the value of oData.  You would have to look at the js to figure out what value of oData gets set, and then use that value in your ruby script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
el.innerHTML="<input id='rad' type='radio' name='table-radiobutton' value='val' />radio";   
var rad = document.getElementById("rad");
rad.onclick=function(){
  alert('clicked');  
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TZTGT/